# spring transactional annotated method without merge call on entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo, transactional

We are using spring roo, and there are some methods in the codebase annotated with @Transactional.

For example,

```
class XService {
    @Transactional
    public Response doSomething(String email) {
        User u = User.findByEmail(email);
        u.setLastModified(Calendar.getInstance());
        return new Response("OK");
    }
}
```

Notice that u.merge() is not called after setLastModified. What should be the value in lastModified column of user table after this method is complete.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on:

1. Method which calls `XService.doSomthing` is annotated with `@Transactional` or not, and it ends with a `RuntimeException` or not.
2. Default Transactional propagation behaviour configuration.

By default, if you call to `XService.doSomthing` from a *controller*, the *User* instance should be updated as `u` is an **attached instance** and method **doesn't throw a runtime exception**.

Look at [this post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ts1/) which I think can explain you interesting information about transaction behaviours on JPA.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Where is "*u.merge()*" called?

On the other side, Roo doesn't annotate each Service method with *@Transactional*, it annotates the entire Service at generated ITD.

Comment: u.merge() is not called at all. Yes, this is not a roo generated method. Please consider adding your answer as a comment as it does not make an attempt to answer the question. Thanks.